# How to Load/Unload a DLL and use its methods inside a script executed by Delphi DWScript

Tags: delphi, plugins, dll, scripting, dwscript

Hi my questions is regarding DLL loading/ binding inside a script because I want to create a scripting interface where there could be plugins based on Delphi DWScript. Some of those plugins could lad DLL to uses functions contained in them. Is DWScript prepared to load DLLs called inside a script?

I was thinking if it already implements the `LoadLibrary`, the `GetProcAddress` (Dynamic loading), or bind statically the methods using the `lib <dllname> [alias <aliasname>]` statement in methods declaration.

Some other scripting mechanism already manages this feature like TMS Scripter, paxScript, paxCompiler.

Comment: IIRC DWScript does not have this functionality out of the box, but you can implement it quite easily if you're willing to do so.

Comment: There is at the moment only an optional COM connector which can access all ActiveX and COM objects, but no low-level direct DLL access at the moment.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but could I implement that feature easily?, maybe creating the link to the proper functions to load and associate the methods addresses?